# C# 4.0: Expression trees vs. CodeDom

Tags: c#, expression-trees, codedom

What are the differences between Expression trees and CodeDom?
Which should I use for which scenario?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Expression trees have a lot in common with (for example) an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). It doesn't map directly to code, but is very amenable to construction from algorithms. For example, if you are parsing a formula:

```
((a + 2) / b)
```

that is:

```
ParameterExpression a = ..., b = ...
var body = Expression.Divide(
    Expression.Add(a, Expression.Constant(2)),
    b);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body,a,b); // optionally with generics
```

In fact, I have done *exactly* this, using a parser that build an object tree, with objects generating the complete expresion via a "visitor" implementation. In .NET 4.0, the richer expression-tree support makes it possible to support most scenarios, and compile it on demand.

Another key use of expressions is that you can *deconstruct* them at runtime, so **in your code** you might have:

```
Foo(x => x.SomeMethod(1, "abc"));
```

and extract the `SomeMethod` method-info, `1` and `"abc"` etc.

---

codedom maps to **code**. It is all about statements etc, **very** similar to how you would write regular code. The most common use of codedom is for code generation, as part of tooling. You *can* use it for dynamic compilation, but to be honest it is harder. I am not a fan. The nice feature is that a codedom tree *might* work for multiple languages.

---

Another contender here should be `DynamicMethod` and/or `ILGenerator`. This **doesn't** map to an AST (expression), and can't be used to generate source-code (codedom), but allows full access to the MSIL tools. Of course, it also requires that you think in terms of stacks etc, but it is **very** efficient and effective for meta-programming.

---

If `ILGenerator` is too hard-core, and codedom is a PITA, then another option is runtime generation of code **as a string**. Then pass that through `CSharpCodeProvider` to compile it. There are parts of the core runtime that do this (`XmlSerializer` IIRC).

---

So to summarise:

- meta-programming: `ILGenerator` or `CSharpCodeProvider`; also `Expression` in 4.0 (but this is quite limited in 3.5)
- handling AST: `Expression`
- parsing at runtime: `Expression`
- code-generation in multiple languages: code-dom

Answer (score 0):

Expression trees are used to build expressions. Creating source code at runtime. CodeDom is used to compile source code. It has to exist before you can build it. Expression trees are more flexible, but a lot harder to use.

If you want to add scripting to your application, use CodeDom. If you want to do very advanced reflection and the likes, use expression trees, but I don't recommend it.